# Loop not giving expected answer - unsure about exit/return/break

Tags: c++, loops, queue, containers

I am testing a simple piece of code in order to learn about using queues (as well as practizing vectors).

I have written this piece of code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

struct msgInfo //contains the attributes as gleaned from the original (IP) message
    {
        int age;
        std::string name;
    };

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<vector<queue<msgInfo>>> nodeInc; //container for messages
int qosLevels = 7; //priority levels
int nodes = 5; //number of nodes
vector<queue<msgInfo>> queuesOfNodes(qosLevels);

int i;
for (i=0; i<nodes; i++)
{
    nodeInc.push_back(queuesOfNodes);
}

msgInfo potato, tomato, domato, bomato;
potato.age = 2;
potato.name = "dud"; 
tomato.age = 3;
tomato.name = "bud"; 
domato.age = 4;
domato.name = "mud"; 
bomato.age = 5;
bomato.name = "pud"; 

nodeInc[2][2].push(potato);
nodeInc[2][2].push(tomato);
nodeInc[2][3].push(domato);
nodeInc[2][3].push(bomato);

for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) //simple loop for testing: for each round, output the age of only one 'msgInfo'
{
    cout << j << endl;
    for (int k = (qosLevels-1); k >= 0; k--)
    {
        if (!nodeInc[2][k].empty())
        {
            cout << nodeInc[2][k].front().age << endl;
            nodeInc[2][k].pop();
            return 0;
        }
        else
            break;

    }
}
```

}

The output I get is

```
0
1
```

but what I am trying to get is

```
0
4
1
5
```

What am I doing wrong here? I can't figure out where my logic is wrong - it seems to me that here it should output the first two elements belonging to the highest filled priority level. I think it has to do with how I am exiting the loop - essentially I want each round of the for loop to only output the age of one msgInfo before 'pop'-ing it - but I have tried exit/return/break and it hasn't worked.

**edit**

I am receiving messages from nodes. These messages need to be put into a queue according to their attributes: node and priority level. I have decided to use a `vector<vector<queue<msgInfo>>>` to do this -> essentially node < priority level < queue for messages > >. When accessing this container, I need it to output the age of one msgInfo at a time - the msgInfo will be the front of the queue of the highest priority level. Not all priority levels will be filled, so it needs to iterate from highest priority level to lowest in order to find the relevant element.

I need to design a loop that will output these one at a time (because other processing needs to be done between each round of the loop).

Comment: If you write down what you intend to do it would be easier to understand your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I can get to is this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) //simple loop for testing: for each round, output the age of only one 'msgInfo'
{
    cout << j << endl;
    for (i = (qosLevels-1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (!nodeInc[2][i].empty())
        {
            cout << nodeInc[2][i].front().age << endl;
            nodeInc[2][i].pop();
            //return 0;  <--------DON'T return. this terminates the program
            break;
        }
        //else
        //    break;
    }
}
```

That returns:

```
0
4
1
5
```

As is stated in the comment, invoking `return 0;` returns from `main()` and therefore terminates the program ( actually kind of a peaceful exit ).

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect `return 0` and `break` to do?

`return 0` exits the entire `main` function, so your program would end once it encounters a non-empty queue.

`break` terminates the innermost enclosing loop (which is `for (i ...)`). In other words, your current logic is:

For each `j` of `0`, `1` do:

If `nodeInc[2][qosLevels - 1]` is not empty, print its front and exit program; otherwise try no more `i`s and do next `j`.

I don't know what the intended behaviour is, but based on the "expected output" you gave, you should replace `return 0` with `break`, and omit the `else` clause entirely.